# Magento 2 in Ionic 3 iframe set cookie SameSite=None instead of the defaulted SameSite=LAX

Tags: ionic-framework, magento, cookies, iframe, magento2

I am having problem add to cart in Ionic framework iframe, the button just stuck at `Adding...` without adding the item to cart.

I noticed there are some errors/warnings in the Network tab. It says the SameSite cookie was set to LAX because it was not found. Refer to the image below.

So my question is how do I set the SameSite=None as the default cookie in Magento 2? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you upgrade to `2.4.2` or higher? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26377

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer or was the comment above an answer already?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try to refactor the domains you use. If everything comes from the same domain, it is not "cross-site response" and this flag is not needed. To know more about why cross-site things are forbidden, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Secondly, try to upgrade to the latest version (as said by @Tarun), which seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, does it affect if I am embedding the website in iframe? Correct me if I'm wrong, I got no control over cross-site / SameSite attribute right? I am using the iframe in Ionic Framework as follow: <iframe src="https://factory.goodniteoutlet.com.my/"></iframe>. It does have HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

Since the current `SameSite` default for Chrome is `None`, third-party cookies can track users across sites. The update changes the default label to `SameSite=Lax`. It means that cookies are set only when the domain in the URL of the browser matches the domain of the cookie. In this situation, we deal with first-party cookies.

As for cookies with the `SameSite=None` label, they must have a secure flag. It’s a guarantee that they are created and sent only through requests made over `HTTPS`.

Unfortunately, some languages and libraries do not support the None value yet. As a result, developers should set the cookie header directly. Check this [Github repository](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples), to discover how to implement `SameSite=None`.